# A front end with write support?

Tags: discussion, api

Ok, so recently reading George's post about a read-only SO for mobile. How hard do you think it'd be to create a read-write front end of SO (nevermind the mobile part)?

Possible problems(and solutions) I can think of:

- Forward compatibility(ie, every change Jeff makes breaks the frontend)
- Captchas. This can be solved by detected a captcha and forwarding it to the user
- Would Jeff like us? I don't believe you are allowed to screenscrape a lot, so would Jeff like us enough to allow us to? (whenever the API is not sufficient, ie, read-only)

Comment: Screen scraping is just as bad as it sounds.

Comment: Tag this `feature-request` and who knows...? Maybe something will happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would hold off until there is a read/write API (if it even happens at all).

The amount of work to get a read/write version working with no API is HUGE. You have to simulate an openid login and carry around cookies and pretend to be a web browser and so on.

As you said even if you got it working it is almost trivial for the powers that be to break it.

I think there are plenty of opportunities around the read only API. That is where the focus should be.

Comment: Waffles, I'm just curious.. Do you really use MSO but not any of the main trilogy sites? lol

Comment: I agree here. It seems to me like the best thing to do is wait. After all, as @waffles mentioned, simulating OpenID is no small feat. And I know that - because I once tried (successfully) to implement OpenID on one of my sites.